# Symmetric difference equivalence relation

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $E\Delta F$ be the symmetric difference, defined as $E\Delta F=(E\setminus F) \cup (F\setminus E)$. The following yields: $E\sim Y$ if and only if $\mu(E\Delta F)=0$, with $\mu$ a measure.
I want to proof that the $\sim$ is an equivalence relation.
For the property of transitivity, I found that $\mu(A\Delta C)\leq \mu((A\Delta B)\cup(B\Delta C))\leq \mu(A\Delta B)+\mu(B\Delta C)=0$. Can somebody explain why these inequalities hold?

Comment: Probably there should be a $\mu(A\Delta C)$ at the left hand side.

Answer (score 6):

This boils down to a set theoretic identity: $A \setminus C \subseteq (A \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus C)$. Indeed, let $x \in A \setminus C$, then $x \in A$ and $x \notin C$. If $x \in A \setminus B$, then we're done. If $x \notin A \setminus B$, then $x \in B$ (since the only way that $x \in A$ and $x \notin A \setminus B$ is that $x \in B$). Now we know that $x \in B$ and $x \notin C$, so $x \in B \setminus C$. Therefore $x \in (A \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus C)$. Similarly, you can prove that $C \setminus A \subseteq (C \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A)$. You should now be able to convince yourself that $A \Delta C \subseteq (A \Delta B) \cup (B \Delta C)$ and hence use the properties of measures to finish off the inequality you're looking for.